# How to fix whirlpool fridge ice maker that makes knocking sounds?

Tags: refrigerator, appliances, noise, ice-maker

My Whirlpool fridge (model WRS571CIDM01) makes knocking sounds every so often. See [video on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Appliances/comments/193uer5/whirlpool_fridge_ice_maker_making_knocking_sounds/).

The sounds seem to be coming from near the top front of the freezer door, where the ice maker sits. I have tried running the removable ice bin in hot water to remove any ice, but this didn't fix it.

What can I do to make the sound go away? Thanks!

Comment: You could try using soft water.  Kidding, I think all ice makers make clunking sounds.  You could try putting a towel temporarily in the bin to see if the cubes dropping into the bin are making the sound.

Comment: Ejecting ice from the tray means dropping it an inch or two. Clunk. Part of the cost of having an ice maker.

Comment: It's also possible that you're hearing a water hammer as the valve is opened and closed, though I wouldn't expect that at this feed rate.

Comment: Mine makes some clunking and buzzing noise as well. It has operated well for 8 years. I assume that's par for the course.

Comment: posting here and on reddit is fine, just don't post the same question on multiple SE sites. It would be nice, though, to post the video directly here, not everyone can or wants to go to every other site in the world when there's perfectly serviceable hosting built right in here.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same refrigerator.

It makes the clunking noise on occasion when the ice cubes move or fall in the tray.  It is part of normal operation and does not indicate a problem.

If you can't live with the sound, turn off the ice maker.

Comment: Same here.  I think it's basically *de rigeur* for refrigerator icemakers.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.